# Minimum sum in quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, analytic-geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral. Also, let $E$ be the midpoint of $AC$ and $F$ the midpoint of $BD$ and $M$ the midpoint of $EF$. The circle $\Gamma$ with center $M$ has radius $r$, such that all the points $A,B,C,D$ lie outside the circle. Prove that, for any point $P$ in the interior of $\Gamma$ $$PA+PB+PC+PD>4r$$[image]

I tried using complex number. One can easily see that $m=\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}$ and $PA+PB+PC+PD=|p-a|+|p-b|+|p-c|+|p-d|$.

I also suspect that the minimum is achieved when $P$ is at the intersection $O$ of the diagonals, or at the intersection of $MO$ and $\Gamma$ when $O$ is outside the circle, but didn't succeed in proving it.

Comment: By "The circle Γ with center M has radius r, such that all the points A,B,C,D lie outside the circle.", do you mean the circle is bounded by the sides of ABCD?

Comment: Not necessarily by the sides, since they can touch the circle. The condition in the statement is equivalent to $MA>r, \: MB>r, \: MC>r, \: MD>r$

Comment: In that case, P could be outside the quadrilateral ABCD.

Comment: Indeed, it could, but I don't see how this affects the result.

Comment: My proof depends heavily on the indicated requirement.

Comment: Could you post it, please?

Comment: It takes some time. Maybe a day or so.

Comment: Sorry to let you know that I must clear some hurdles before I can have it posted.

Comment: Thank you so much for your interest! Can't wait to see it, when it's ready

Comment: I have posted a simpler question in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235717/how-many-iterations-are-needed.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, let us prove your last claim.

> If $ABCD$ is a convex quadrilateral and $PA+PB+PC+PD$ is minimal, $P=AC\cap BD$.

If we assume that $Q$ makes $QA+QB+QC+QD$ minimal we may consider the ellipse $\Gamma_{AB}$ with foci at $A,B$ through $Q$ and the ellipse $\Gamma_{CD}$ with foci at $C,D$ through $Q$. With our assumptions $\Gamma_{AB}$ and $\Gamma_{CD}$ have to be tangent, otherwise it would be possible to simultaneously decrease both $QA+QB$ and $QC+QD$ by moving $Q$ along the segment joining the two intersection points. By the optical property of the ellipse, the commont tangent at $Q$ must be perpendicular to both the angle bisector of $\widehat{CQD}$ and the angle bisector of $\widehat{AQB}$: it follows that the minimum is unique and it is achieved at $AC\cap BD$.

[image]

Your question now is much simplified. If $P=AC\cap BD$ lies inside $\Gamma$, it is enough to show that $BD=PB+PD\geq 2r$ and $AC=PA+PC\geq 2r$, with at least one inequality being tight.

Answer (score 2):

**Lemma:** If $ABCD$ is a convex quadrilateral and $PA+PB+PC+PD$ is minimal, then $P=AC \cap BD$.

**Proof:** Let $Q=AC \cap BD$.
By the triangle inequality in triangle PAC we have
$$PA+PC \geq AC=QA+QC$$
with equality if and only if $P \in (AC)$.

Same wway
$$PB+PD \geq BD=QB+QD$$

with equality if and only if $P \in (BD)$.

This shows that 
$$PA+PB+PC+PD \geq QA+QB+QC+QD$$
with equality if and only if $P\in (AC)\cap (BD)=\{Q\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let (1) A’ be the midpoint of AB. B’ C’ and D’ are similarly defined; and (2) A’’ be the midpoint of A’B’. B’’ C’’ and D’’ are similarly defined.

Fact-1) B’’MD’’ and A''MC'' are a straight lines.

[image]
By midpoint theorem, BB’EC’ is a parallelogram with BB’’ = B’’E. This, together with the fact that FM = ME, makes MB’’ // BF. Similarly MD’’ // DF. Therefore, B’’MD’’ is a straight line. The same is true for A’’MC’’.

---

Fact-2) PA + PB + PC + PD > A’B’ + B’C’ + C’D’ + ‘DA’
[image]
By the triangular inequality and midpoint theorem, we have:-

PA + PB + PC + PD = (PA + PC) + [PB + PD] > (AC) + [BD] = (B’C’ + A’D’) + [A’B’ + C’D’].

---

Construction: Thro’ M, draw D’’MB’’//BD and draw A’’MC’’//AC. Then, form the parallelogram A’’B’’C’’D’’.

Fact-3) (A’B’) + B’C’ + C’D’ + D’A’ > A’’ B’’ + B’’C ‘’+ C’’D’’ + D’’A’’
This is obviously true just by visual inspection.

---

Fact-4) A’’ B’’ + B’’C ‘’+ C’’D’’ + D’’A’’ = MA’ + MB’ + MC’ + MD’.

[image]
By the midpoint theorem, this is true by considering the diagonals of A’B’C’D’.

---

Result follows because each of the MA’ (and MB’…. ) is longer than the radius of the red circle, **provided that the red circle is bounded by the sides of ABCD**.