# How many iterations are needed

Tags: geometry

In the figure, $ABCD$ is a convex quadrilateral with $A_1, B_1, C_1, D_1$ as the midpoints of its sides. P is a point inside $ABCD$ and let $s = PA + PB + PC + PD$.

[image]

Clearly, $A_1B_1C_1D_1$ is a parallelogram and its perimeter is smaller than the original ABCD. The iteration process goes on until $A_nB_nC_nD_n$ is reached. The question is:- ”what is the smallest n such that $s \gt A_nB_n + B_nC_n + C_nD_n + D_nA_n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is two iterations ($n=2$) because the minimum value of $s$ is equal to the perimeter of $A_1B_1C_1D_1$. The minimum value of $s$, as proven in the linked question, occurs when $P$ is at the intersection of $AC$ and $BD$. So $s_{min}=AC+BD$.

Because $A_1B_1C_1D_1$ is constructed from the mid-points of $ABCD$, $AC$ is parallel to $A_1B_1$ and $C_1D_1$ and $BD$ is parallel to $D_1A_1$ and $B_1C_1$. Since the triangle $ABC$ is similar to $A_1BB_1$, $AC$ is two times as long as $A_1B_1$. Also since the triangle $ACD$ is similar to $D_1C_1D$, $AC$ is two times as long as $C_1D_1$. So $AC$ is equal to $A_1B_1+C_1D_1$. Similar arguments can be used to show that $BD=B_1C_1+D_1A_1$.

So, $s_{min}=AC+BD=A_1B_1+B_1C_1+D_1A_1$ showing that the inequality $s>A_nB_n+B_nC_n+D_nA_n$ just barely fails for $n=1$. For the inequality to hold, another iteration is required so the minimum $n$ is two.

Comment: I guess it is just a matter of notation. $s > A_nB_n+B_nC_n+C_nD_n + D_nA_n$ just barely fails for **n = 0** if $A_0$ means A.....